# OctoberCMS (Laravel) Field select statement

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I need to add to my relation strings like this format: `Name Surname` (the post) and the post I need to take from another table (at this relation I have only post_id). How can I take `post.title` using `fields.yaml` file?

```
    professors:
        label: Преподаватель
        descriptionFrom: description
        span: auto
        required: 1
        type: relation
        select: concat(name, ' ', surname, ' ', post_id) // Already working
        select: SELECT title FROM titamik_cio_post WHERE id=post_id as post concat(name, ' ', surname, ' ', post) // ??????
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest approach is to define a scope in the related model.

```
    professors:
        label: Преподаватель
        nameùfrom: title
        descriptionFrom: description
        span: auto
        required: 1
        type: relation
        scope: yourScopeName
```

You need to define your scope in the **related form model class** as per the documentation (https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes).